# a program to apply the following transformation function to a grayscale image

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, grayscale

I want to apply following transformation function to a grayscale image, i know how to apply it to the following function,

[image: transformation function]

my question is how do i apply a program to the following transformation function,

[image: what i wanted to be done]

code so far,

```
clear;
pollen = imread('Fig3.10(b).jpg');
u = double(pollen);
[nx ny] = size(u)
nshades = 256;
r1 = 80; s1 = 10; % Transformation by piecewise linear function.
r2 = 140; s2 = 245;
for i = 1:nx
 for j = 1:ny
 if (u(i,j)< r1)
 uspread(i,j) = ((s1-0)/(r1-0))*u(i,j)
 end
 if ((u(i,j)>=r1) & (u(i,j)<= r2))
 uspread(i,j) = ((s2 - s1)/(r2 - r1))*(u(i,j) - r1)+ s1;
 end
 if (u(i,j)>r2)
 uspread(i,j) = ((255 - s2)/(255 - r2))*(u(i,j) - r2) + s2;
 end
 end
end
hist= zeros(nshades,1);
for i=1:nx
 for j=1:ny
 for k=0:nshades-1
 if uspread(i,j)==k
 hist(k+1)=hist(k+1)+1;
 end
 end
 end
end
plot(hist);
pollenspreadmat = uint8(uspread);
imwrite(pollenspreadmat, 'pollenspread.jpg');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure says that for any intensities that are between `A` and `B`, they should be set to `C`.  All you have to do is modify your two `for` loops so that for any values between `A` and `B`, set the output location to `C`. I'll also assume the range is inclusive. You can simply remove the first and last `if` conditions and use the middle one:

```
for i = 1:nx
    for j = 1:ny
       if ((u(i,j)>=r1) && (u(i,j)<= r2))
           uspread(i,j) = C;
       end
    end
end
```

`C` is a constant that you would set yourself.  Usually for segmentation, this result is very high to distinguish the foreground from the background. You have a `uint8` image here, so `C = 255;` would work.

However, I would recommend you achieve a more vectorized solution.  Avoid `for` loops and use `logical` indexing instead:

```
uspread = u;
uspread(u >= r1 & u <= r2) = C;
```

Comment: how can i define `C`

Comment: That's up to you. You define it yourself. Some people like to choose a large value to segment things out from the image. Maybe 255.

Comment: No problem at all!

Comment: I can also show you how to modify your current code for this transformation. I'll edit my post.

Comment: That will be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks in advanced